# In python ,how can we perform conditional operations list where items or elements of list are keywords

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, operation

tup=(1,'2',3.3,(1,4))

lst=list(map(type,tup))

print(lst)

for item in last:

if(item==class str)

print("success")

## here "class str" is keyword but it is also the item of lst, any possible syntax to do conditional operations on keywords

Comment: Please, improve the quality of your question. To add code, write this: ``` Code ```

Comment: `type(item) == str` perhaps?

Comment: `item is str` perhaps?

Comment: `isinstance(item, str)` perhaps?

Comment: FWIW, `str` *is* the class object. You don't need to prefix it with `class` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want

```
tup=(1,'2',3.3,(1,4))  #this is my tuple 
lst=list(map(type,tup))   #It stores the data types of elements of tuple in a list
print(lst)  #prints the list
for item in lst:
   if item is str: # here "class str" is keyword but it is a item of lst,is there any possible syntax

        print("succesful")
```